# Simple and Efficient FFT C or C++ code for HLS implementation

Tags: c++, c, fft, implementation, intel-fpga

I'm working on my project and it's related to speech processing. I have to implement parts of the project on an Intel FPGA board using Intel HLS Compiler that converts C code to RTL code for FPGA Implementation.

I need to convert time domain signals to frequency domain using FFT in order to process the input signals of speech.I don't know how does FFT algorithm work i just know that it would be more efficient to use a FFT instead of DFT for hardware implementation.

I need a simple radix-2 code that doesn't involve malloc() function and complex.h library if a code uses them i have to port the code, since i don't have a lot of experience with C it would be hard and time consuming for me to port the code that is only a small part of the project;math.h library is allowed to be included and can be implemented in HLS.

I have searched and found many C and C++ implementations of FFT algorithm but most of them need porting to be suitable for HLS implementation.
I have found following code and i think it's the best match for my implementation since it does not include complex library and malloc function : https://gist.github.com/Determinant/db7889995f08fe982418

I can't understand some parts of aforementioned code:

-What is the following definition used for?

```
#define comp_mul_self(c, c2) \
```

-What are the fft function inputs? because the input variables names are not clear enough for me.

```
void fft(const Comp *sig, Comp *f, int s, int n, int inv)
```

I would really appreciate if someone with enough knowledge of FFT algorithm could comment the important parts of the code and if there is a better C or C++ code for my implementation please point me the directions.

here is the full code from link above:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Comp {
    /* comp of the form: a + bi */
    double a, b;
} Comp;

Comp comp_create(double a, double b) {
    Comp res;
    res.a = a;
    res.b = b;
    return res;
}

Comp comp_add(Comp c1, Comp c2) {
    Comp res = c1;
    res.a += c2.a;
    res.b += c2.b;
    return res;
}

Comp comp_sub(Comp c1, Comp c2) {
    Comp res = c1;
    res.a -= c2.a;
    res.b -= c2.b;
    return res;
}

Comp comp_mul(Comp c1, Comp c2) {
    Comp res;
    res.a = c1.a * c2.a - c1.b * c2.b;
    res.b = c1.b * c2.a + c1.a * c2.b;
    return res;
}


void comp_print(Comp comp) {
    printf("%.6f + %.6f i\n", comp.a, comp.b);
}

/* const double PI = acos(-1); */
#define PI 3.141592653589793
#define SQR(x) ((x) * (x))

/* Calculate e^(ix) */
Comp comp_euler(double x) {
    Comp res;
    res.a = cos(x);
    res.b = sin(x);
    return res;
}

#define comp_mul_self(c, c2) \
do { \
    double ca = c->a; \
    c->a = ca * c2->a - c->b * c2->b; \
    c->b = c->b * c2->a + ca * c2->b; \
} while (0)

void dft(const Comp *sig, Comp *f, int n, int inv) {
    Comp ep = comp_euler(2 * (inv ? -PI : PI) / (double)n);
    Comp ei, ej, *pi = &ei, *pj = &ej, *pp = &ep;
    int i, j;
    pi->a = pj->a = 1;
    pi->b = pj->b = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        f[i].a = f[i].b = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            f[i] = comp_add(f[i], comp_mul(sig[j], *pj));
            comp_mul_self(pj, pi);
        }
        comp_mul_self(pi, pp);
    }
}

void fft(const Comp *sig, Comp *f, int s, int n, int inv) {
    int i, hn = n >> 1;
    Comp ep = comp_euler((inv ? PI : -PI) / (double)hn), ei;
    Comp *pi = &ei, *pp = &ep;
    if (!hn) *f = *sig;
    else
    {
        fft(sig, f, s << 1, hn, inv);
        fft(sig + s, f + hn, s << 1, hn, inv);
        pi->a = 1;
        pi->b = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < hn; i++)
        {
            Comp even = f[i], *pe = f + i, *po = pe + hn;
            comp_mul_self(po, pi);
            pe->a += po->a;
            pe->b += po->b;
            po->a = even.a - po->a;
            po->b = even.b - po->b;
            comp_mul_self(pi, pp);
        }
    }
}

void print_result(const Comp *sig, const Comp *sig0, int n) {
    int i;
    double err = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Comp t = sig0[i];
        t.a /= n;
        t.b /= n;
        comp_print(t);
        t = comp_sub(t, sig[i]);
        err += t.a * t.a + t.b * t.b;
    }
    printf("Error Squared = %.6f\n", err);
}

void test_dft(const Comp *sig, Comp *f, Comp *sig0, int n) {
    int i;
    puts("## Direct DFT ##");
    dft(sig, f, n, 0);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        comp_print(f[i]);
    puts("----------------");
    dft(f, sig0, n, 1);
    print_result(sig, sig0, n);
    puts("################");
}

void test_fft(const Comp *sig, Comp *f, Comp *sig0, int n) {
    int i;
    puts("## Cooley–Tukey FFT ##");
    fft(sig, f, 1, n, 0);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        comp_print(f[i]);
    puts("----------------------");
    fft(f, sig0, 1, n, 1);
    print_result(sig, sig0, n);
    puts("######################");
}

int main() {
    int n, i, k;
    Comp *sig, *f, *sig0;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    n = 1 << k;
    sig = (Comp *)malloc(sizeof(Comp) * (size_t)n);
    sig0 = (Comp *)malloc(sizeof(Comp) * (size_t)n);
    f = (Comp *)malloc(sizeof(Comp) * (size_t)n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sig[i].a = rand() % 10;
        sig[i].b = 0;
    }
    puts("## Original Signal ##");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        comp_print(sig[i]);
    puts("#####################");
    test_dft(sig, f, sig0, n);
    test_fft(sig, f, sig0, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please change your tag from `c++` to `c`. those are totally different programming languages.

Comment: Sorry, just found out myself. ;-) (Comment already deleted.)

Comment: IMHO, `comp_mul_self()` is a macro to handle the special case of `c = comp_mul(c, c2);` (doing the multiplication for `c` in place). The `do`/`while (0)` is just a common macro trick to enclose the scope `{` `}` with something making the whole one statement (which has to be suffixed with `;` as usual).

Comment: @Scheff why not using an in place function with a pointer instead of a macro?

Comment: @skratchi.at Changed the subject and tags. ;-)

Comment: _why not using an in place function with a pointer instead of a macro?_ This is something you have to ask the author. ;-) `inline` is available in C since C99. Before it was usual to write inline functions in macros.

Comment: @Scheff thanks; what about fft function inputs? can you tell what is each input's role in computing fft of a signal?

Comment: OT: regarding: `sig[i].a = rand() % 10;`  in `main()`,  Since the function: `srand()` (which should only be called once in the whole program) was not called, the same sequence of values will be returned by `rand()` everytime the program is run..

Comment: OT: regarding this kind of statement: `sig = (Comp *)malloc(sizeof(Comp) * (size_t)n);`  1) In C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc  2) When calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()`, `calloc()` and/or `realloc()`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful